# $F \cong \mathrm{Set}(-, A)$ when $F$ is adjoint to $\bar{F}$

Tags: category-theory

I can’t do the following. I figure it has something to do with Yoneda lemma. Also I guessed that $A = \{0, 1\}$ when $F$ is the power set functor. In general I have no idea how to find $A$.

> **Exercise 95.**
> A general converse to the last example.
> Suppose that $F \colon \mathrm{Set}^{\mathrm{op}} \to \mathrm{Set}$ is a functor such that for the corresponding functor $\bar{F} \colon \mathrm{Set} \to \mathrm{Set}^{\mathrm{op}}$ we have that $\bar{F} \dashv F$.
> Then there is a set $A$ such  that $F$ is naturally isomorphic to $\mathrm{Set}(-, A)$.
>
> ([Original screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5zQs.png))

Comment: Out of personal interest, where is this question from?

Comment: @JendrikStelzner these notes https://webspace.science.uu.nl/~ooste110/syllabi/catsmoeder.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $F$ and $\bar{F}$ be as you describe. Then for all $\newcommand{\Set}{\mathrm{Set}} x \in \Set$ and $\newcommand{\op}{\mathrm{op}} y \in \Set^{\op}$, we have $\Set^{\op}(\bar{F} x , y) \cong \Set(x, F y)$, natural in $x$ and $y$. Fixing $x :\equiv 1$, we have $\Set^{\op}(\bar{F} 1 , y) \cong \Set(1, F y) \cong F y$. So $\Set^{\op}(\bar{F} 1, -) \cong F$. But $\Set^{\op}(\bar{F} 1, -) \cong \Set(-, \bar{F} 1)$. This lends $\Set(-,\bar{F} 1) \cong F$.

Comment: thank you! yeah that was a no brainer. i shouldve just asked for a hint.

Comment: Yes @famousmortimer , it's better to include details in your original post explaining what you tried and where you got stuck